# Как реализовать небольшой редактор электрических схем?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть в том, что есть некое рабочее окно с прибором (картинка), который измеряет различные параметры электрического кабеля. Справа от этого окна есть элементы (различные марки кабелей) из которых собирается схема. Эти элементы необходимо перетаскивать курсором в рабочее окно и собирать саму схему, с помощью соединительных линий (проводов) и отслеживать правильность ее сборки.
Вопрос в том как реализовать это перетаскивание, соединение элементов схемы и отслежку правильности сборки?
Читал про Drag’n’Drop, но не знаю как реализовать соединительные линии правильно. Есть мысли добавить на концах каждого элемента кнопки и при их нажатии производить соединение, но хотелось бы просто при нажатии мыши вести курсором к необходимому разъёму прибора и, чтобы за курсором следовал провод.
С реализацией проверки правильности встал в тупик. Думаю при соединении назначать, например, элементу схемы какой-то идентификатор, который соответствует разъёму самого прибора и через условие потом проверять, насколько это будет правильно?

Comment: Мысли верные, но вот с анимацией провода будут проблемы. Если не шибко анимировать их, то нужно будет заранее отрисовать все положения. А так да, у каждого элемента свой `id`, у каждого входа тоже с проверкой на совместимость. Если бы можно было еще на такой схеме отслеживать ток/напряжение/сопротивление, было бы вообще шикарно))

Comment: По моему проще это было бы реализовать на ActionScript. ИМХО!)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки [gojs](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html). Там точно найдете то, что вам нужно и даже больше!